# Strech image to fit gridlayout in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I was trying to get an image to fill out my entire grid, but it would leave parts of it blank - even while defining allow_strech and keep_ratio. How do I get my image to fill out the entire grid?
(The problem is the width in this case as the height is fine, but I assume it's to do with the image itself and not the code..)

python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

GUI = Builder.load_file('style.kv')
# Window.size = (2224, 1668)


class NotebookScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.rows = 1
        super(NotebookScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)



class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return NotebookScreen()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<NotebookScreen>
    FloatLayout:
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            id: tool_bar
            cols: 1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            id: notebook_grid
            size_hint: 1, .9
            pos_hint: {"top": .9, "left": 0}
            cols: 1
            Image:
                id: notebook_image
                source: 'images/notebook.jpg'
                allow_strech: True
                keep_ratio: False 
                pos: self.pos
                size_hint: 1, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Spelling error:

```
allow_strech: True
```

should be:

```
allow_stretch: True
```

Comment: Wow it's been hours and I couldn't figure out why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GridLayout`, use `BoxLayout`